# Why does this css throw a sintactic error?

Tags: css, validation

I check my scss generated css code in the W3C validator, and it throws several errors (see below) for this piece of code:

```
body {
  --ajuste: calc((1400px - 100vw) / 1400);
  font-size: 1em;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none !important;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) {
  body {
    font-size: 6.7142857143px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 1400px) {
  body {
    font-size: calc(1.1428571429vw - var(--ajuste) * 4);
  }
}
```

This is the feedback:

```
> Error de análisis sintáctico --ajuste: calc((1400px - 100vw) / 1400);
> Error de análisis sintáctico [: 1em; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: #fff; text-align: center; -webkit-touch-callout: none !important; } @media screen and (max-width: 750px)]
> Propiedad no válida : font-size Error de análisis sintáctico var(--ajuste) * 4)
```

"Error de análisis sintáctico" is spanish for "Sintactic analysis error", and "Propiedad no válida" stands for "non-valid property".
I can't imagine what the problem is here, any help, please?

Comment: it works fine, you are propabaly using an old validator that doesn't recognize CSS variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that there's a feature request that's currently open, I'd say it is not supported yet:

[Please add support for CSS variables ("custom properties"), a widely supported and crucial feature. #111](https://github.com/w3c/css-validator/issues/111)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought it was on me